# CSS Grid item overflowing out of body (making scrollbar appear)

Tags: css, sass, ckeditor, overflow, css-grid

Here is a clip of the behavior I'm trying to fix: https://streamable.com/vr0rf

I don't understand why I have that white gap on the right, when I hover over elements in the dev tools it looks like there's nothing there. It's caused by something inside the "editor" div which contains a CKEditor5 text editor. I can fix it by setting body overflow to hidden but then I can't scroll when the window is narrow enough for the real elements to overflow.

```
html,
body,
#root {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "nav    editor"
    "footer footer";

  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;

  ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}

#editor {
  grid-area: editor;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 300px;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the actual HTML it's hard to say anything. This is why you should post snippets. Watching the video is very annoying because your mouse is quickly jumping around and it's hardly possible to check for anything.

I'd suggest setting the body's width to 100vw (instead of 100%) and max-width to 100%. That should prevent any horizontal scrolling.

If that doesn't help (again, hard to test without your actual scripts/code), try changing the settings for your grid element's widths to viewport related relative values and set min- and max-width values.

```
body {
   width: 100vw;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```